# Match text content and apply style

Tags: html, css, user-interface, css-selectors

I have some parts of text that I want to have custom styles applied to:

```
<span class="filename">ExportFileName_datefollows_%1$tY.txt<span/>
```

I'm wondering if (A) I can select the `%1$tY` part and (B) have it displayed with custom styles (color changes, or border, or entire replacement with a select with multiple options element)

Do you think this is possible? How would you do it?

Comment: With CSS only or is JavaScript a possible solution?

Comment: CSS only would be great, but JS is an option. The thing is I'd like to keep 'ExportFileName_datefollows_%1$tY.txt' intact so that it can be directly submitted to the database. %1$tY will display the year in the backend, but this format is too foreign for users.

Comment: It's not possible to style only parts of that string. Though you can add a second element on top of the existing one with the same html content and wrap the %1$tY via JavaScript in a seperated span. This would keep the existing `.filename` intact.

Comment: @KilianStinson what do you mean by second element on top of the existing one?

Comment: Something like this http://jsfiddle.net/vLEMN/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See this fiddle: 
http://jsfiddle.net/vLEMN/1/

HTML:

```
<div class="filename-wrapper">
    <span class="filename"> 
        ExportFileName_datefollows_%1$tY.txt 
    </span>
    <span class="filename-clone">
    </span>
</div>
```

jQuery:

```
var cloneContent = $('.filename').html();
cloneContent = cloneContent.replace('%1$tY', '<span class="stylable">%1$tY</span>');
$('.filename-clone').html(cloneContent);
```

CSS:

```
.filename-wrapper {
    position: relative;
}

.filename-clone {
    background-color: #fff;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}

.stylable {
    color: red;
}
```

It's no the most dynamic solution, but should be fine if you always need to select `%1$tY`
and keeps the original `.filename` content intact.